# how to change the color of select in ant-design?

Tags: antd

**My problem:**

when I use the ant-design

I want to change the color of select when I `hover&focus` this select menu!

but it doesn't work!

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uod1l.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSTG0.png)

I tried to rewrite lots of code about this, but it doesn't work!

```
ant-select-selector:hover{
     border-color:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `border` with an `!important` override. Include also the `focus-within` selector

```
.ant-select-selector:hover, .ant-select-selector:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: yeah, but there are some problems. when I select some items, the items of parent show the origin color.

Comment: @DonjingZheng Please do not try to edit my answer with additional problems that you encountered using my solution. Just make a comment about my solution or edit your question with the additional issues that you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
ant-select-selector:hover{
     border-color:1px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: hello thanks your comments. but it doesn't work~